# Pointwise Supremum of Quasi-convex Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

In Boyd and Vandenberghe, *Convex Optimization*, page 102, I read that if function $g(x,y)$ is quasi-convex in $x$ for each $y$, then
$$
f(x)=\sup\limits_{y\in C}(w(y)g(x,y))
$$
is also quasi-convex, where $w(y)\geq0$.

**My question**: If the set $C$ depends on $x$, for example, $C_x=\{y:y\leq x\}$, then under what conditions can this conclusion still hold?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Typically you can solve such problems by introducing an indicator function $I_{C_x}(y)$ (for your example it takes the value $0$ if $y\leq x$, $\infty$ otherwise):
$$f(x) = \sup_{y \in C} \left\{ w(y)(g(x,y)-I_{C_x}(y)) \right\}$$
The condition is now that $g(x,y)-I_{C_x}(y)$ is quasiconvex in $x$ for each $y$, which is not true, so we cannot use this trick.

Going back to page 102, it was concluded that $f$ is quasiconvex, because $f(x)\leq \alpha$ iff
$$w(y)g(x,y) \leq \alpha \quad \forall y \in C.$$
In other words, the sublevel set of $f$ is convex, since it is the intersection of convex sets. If you replace $C$ with $C_x$, this argument no longer holds, because $C$ depends on $x$. In other words, the sublevel set of $f$ cannot easily be expressed as the intersection of convex sets.

Comment: Thanks! I need some time to understand it...

Comment: I got it. But I'm wondering what if we replace "sup" by "max" (provided it exists)? Does it matter?

Comment: if the max exists, it does not matter

Comment: Thanks. I think the indicator function should take the value of $-\infty$ when $y>x$, is it right?

Comment: Here comes another question. The indicator function $I_{C_x}$ depends upon $x$, thus I cannot prove function $g(x,y)+I_{C_x}(y)$ is still quasi-convex in $x$...

Comment: @Huaixin you are right about the $-\infty$ (however, I subtract the indicator function instead of changing its function value); I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you mean $f(x)\leq\alpha$ iff $w(y)g(x,y)\leq\alpha\ \forall y\in C_x$? I'm a little confused about this since set $C_x$ is not fixed.

Comment: @Huaixin you are right, this is by no means easy. I now think that $f$ is often not quasiconvex.